# clojure: correctly passing things to vector using a loop?

Tags: clojure

I'm having trouble figuring out how to abstract some simple code into a loop/map/for structure. I have the following code which works, in the sense that it gives me the output I want:

```
(let    
    [recipe [1 1 2] 
    voicing [0 2 4]
    counts (range (count voicing))
    scale C]
    (map vector
        (make-scale recipe voicing scale 0)
        (make-scale recipe voicing scale 1)
        (make-scale recipe voicing scale 2)
    )
```

the output is:

```
 ([:C :E :G] [:D :F :B] [:E :A :C] [:G :B :D] [:A :C :F] [:B :E :G] [:D :F :A])
```

I'm basically using the "(map vector arg1 arg2...)" call to interleave 3 seqs.

obviously I need to make the final step of removing the duplicate calls to make-scale. problem is, I need:

```
 (map vector arg1 arg2 arg2)
```

and all the ways I know how to use a loop give me the results of the loop in a seq:

```
 (map vector (arg1 arg2 arg3))
```

what's the best way to refactor the intial code, so that I only have a single function call to make-scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
(apply map vector (map (partial make-scale recipe voicing scale) [0 1 2]))
```

In general, `apply` helps whenever you have a sequence and want to use its elements as consecutive arguments of a function.  You can also prepend some arguments to the list (in this case the `vector` argument is prepended as the first argment to `map`.)

In Clojure many stdlib functions expect an expanded list (`vector` and practically every other collection constructor, `str`.) I think this is by design - you are expected to use `apply` with them.

The sequence in question can even be infinite (i.e. lazy infinite), of course if the function being applied handles lazy infinite argument lists. This works fine, even though `concat` is being applied to an infinite list of lists:

```
(take 7 (apply concat (cycle [[1 2 3]])))
>>> (1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

Comment: @PaulSanwald Wait, I'm just getting started! I looove Clojure's `apply` :)

Comment: yeah the answer is even better now :). another thing that I wasn't understanding was that apply will let you prepend arguments as well.

Comment: Also consider `(apply map vector (for [some-meaningful-name [0 1 2]] (make-scale recipe voicing scale some-meaningful-name)))` - `for` often winds up being nicer than `map` when you're not just mapping an already-existing function, though I don't have enough domain knowledge re: scales to say if this is such a case.

Comment: @amalloy Agreed, `map partial` might be less readable than `for` especially if OP has a good candidate for `some-meaningful-name`. I am leaving it as-is, since it's not at the core of the question.